# Trying to Redirect in React after Login with Axios (Separate Frontend & Backend)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

The answer to my question probably already exists, but I've run out of ideas of where/how to check.

I'm building a project with a teammate split into separate Frontend and Backends.

After the login form is submitted, I'm able to successfully set an authorization token in `localStorage` but get an error with trying to redirect the user from the root "/" page to a "/home" page where the main content will be. I don't think `<Link to="/home" />` is the right solution, not sure if `<Redirect />` is. I was trying `axios.get("/home")` but this is the error that I get:

```
GEThttp://localhost:3000/home
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 5ms]

catch Error: Request failed with status code 404
    createError createError.js:16
    settle settle.js:17
    handleLoad xhr.js:62
    dispatchXhrRequest xhr.js:37
    xhrAdapter xhr.js:13
    dispatchRequest dispatchRequest.js:52
    promise callback*request Axios.js:61
    method Axios.js:76
    wrap bind.js:9
    handleSubmit Login.js:32
    React 14
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:646
    React 4
```

CODE:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Login(props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");

  function handleChange (e) {
    if (e.target.name === "email") {
      setEmail(e.target.value);
    } else {
      setPassword(e.target.value);
    }
  }

  async function handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/user/login", { email, password});
      console.log(res);
        if (!res.data.error) {

        localStorage.setItem("authorization", "Bearer: " + res.data); // works
        return await axios.get("/home");
      } else {
        console.log("1st", res.data.error)
      }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("catch", error);
  }

  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit } >
      { errorMsg && <div className="errorMsg">Error: { errorMsg }</div> }
      <label>Email: <input type="email" name="email" value={email} onChange={ handleChange } placeholder="you@email.com" required/></label><br />
      <label>Password: <input type="password" name="password" value={password} onChange={ handleChange } placeholder="********" required/></label>
      <button type="submit" name="button">Submit</button>
    </form>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `useHistory` from `react-router-dom`. After successfully set token then use `history.push('/route-name')` to go to your preferred page.

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

const history = useHistory();

async function handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/user/login", { email, password});
      console.log(res);
        if (!res.data.error) {

        localStorage.setItem("authorization", "Bearer: " + res.data); // works
        history.push("/home");
      } else {
        console.log("1st", res.data.error)
      }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("catch", error);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are confused with routing in `frontend` and routing in `backend`. Routing in backend is related with your endpoints: `/api/user/login`, `/api/user` and so on. Those return data when you make a *http* call (with `axios` in your case).
Routing in frontend is related with the flow between pages (a.k.a navigation). So `/home` is a route in your frontend and `react-router-dom` has access to it. To be able to jump to new pages, the most straightforward way is to call `history.push("/home")` using the `useHistory()` hook (inside your React component) as Zahid showed or accessing `history` as props if `<Login>` component is wrapped by a `<Route>` component